# Ordering into Jquery by name and not by id

Tags: jquery

I have a jquery ajax function to retrieve car brands.

On the server side the query is ordered by brand name.

But when it comes to jquery the list is presented ordered by id .

How can i sort into jquery by name and not by id?

Maintaining  the server-side ordering ?

```
var $optionsBrand = $("#BrandId").html($("<option />").val('').text('select one'));
    if($response) {                        
        $optionsBrand.prop("disabled", false);
        $.each($response, function(id, value){
            var $opt = new Option(value, id);
            $optionsBrand.append($opt);        
        });
    }
```

From the server side, my SQL query returns the list in this way :

```
4-BMW
3-FORD
2-KIA
5-Nissan
1-Volkswagen
```

And the Jquery side reorder into this way:

```
1-Volkswagen
2-KIA
3-FORD
4-BMW
5-Nissan
```

How can i maintain the server-side ordering by name?

Comment: I don't see anything in your code that would change the data being sent from the server, let alone re-sort it.

Comment: Send the data as array not object. Objects don't guarantee sort order especially with numeric keys. Show sample of response to confirm it is object or array. I'm pretty sure it is an object based on how you process it

Comment: sample json: {1: "Volkswagen", 2: "KIA", 3: "FORD", 4: "BMW", 5: "Nissan",…}

Comment: right.. as i suspected it is an object. Send array to maintain order or else you have to map that to array and sort the resultant array

Comment: trying to discover how can i send an array, any sugestion ?

Comment: What language are you using server side? And how are you generating current json?

Comment: PHP, CakePHP 2 : 
$carBrands = Hash::combine(
 $carBrands,'{n}.ID', array('%s', '{n}.BRAND' )
);      
echo json_encode( $carBrands );

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are receiving an object you need to map that to an array and sort it again. The ideal is to send an array from server instead as arrays guarantee order, objects don't

```js
var $response ={1: "Volkswagen", 2: "KIA", 3: "FORD", 4: "BMW", 5: "Nissan"}

var sorted = Object.keys($response).map(function(key){
    return {id: key, name: $response[key]};
}).sort(function(a,b){
   return a.name.localeCompare(b.name);
});

console.log(sorted)
```

Comment: How can i append into $optionsBrand, the sorted values? as it was done into the each loop:
 $.each($response, function(id, value){
            var $opt = new Option(value, id);
            $optionsBrand.append($opt);        
        });

Comment: i try to pass a key =>value array but again it was sorted by index and not by name

Comment: `$.each(sorted, function(index, item){ ... new Option(item.name, item.id)...`

Comment: great now it is solved! thank you so much charlietfl

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this by JS

```
$optionsBrand.sort(function (a, b) {
  if (a.name > b.name) {
    return 1;
  }else if (a.name < b.name) {
    return -1;
  }
  return 0;
});
```